# How to find out which version of Synplify you're using in a tcl script

Tags: version, tcl, synthesis

I like to start a Tcl-Script in Synplify. Depending from the version of Synplify, it should do different things. But how can I find out which verion of Synplify it is, in the script? Is there any variable?

Thanks,
Kai

Answer (score 0):

The `synhooks` (search the online help for "synhooks", there's some reasonable documentation) file can contain a function to run when Synplify opens.  This function has the version passed to it as one of the parameters.  I guess you could write that out to a file and read it with your other script.

I can't find a more pleasant way of doing it, sorry!

Comment: I already thought about the idea with the synhooks. The problem is that the synhook-function starts when my tcl-script has already finshed.

Comment: Run a synhook when the Application starts.  Write the ID to a file.  Then you can use the *file* for your ID

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. Just use `program_version`.